# elegant time-of-week function

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that returns bool based on whether the time is currently in any number of pre-defined "hotzones." Timezone is America/Chicago (UTC - 0600). The following works:

```
$d = 60*60;                    /* duration of hotzone */
$o = -(3*24+18)*3600;          /* offset to bring UNIX epoch to 12a Sun local*/
$curTime = (time()-$o)%604800; /* time since 12a Sun */

/* Hotzones */
$hotTime = array();
$hotTime[0 ] = (0*24+11)*3600; /* 11a Sun */
$hotTime[1 ] = (0*24+18)*3600; /*  6p Sun */
$hotTime[2 ] = (2*24+19)*3600; /*  7p Tue */
$hotTime[3 ] = (3*24+ 6)*3600; /*  6a Wed */
$hotTime[4 ] = (3*24+11)*3600; /* 11a Wed */

$hotTimes = count($hotTime);

for ($i = $hotTimes-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
  if (($curTime > $hotTime[$i])&&($curTime < $hotTime[$i]+$d)) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```

However, I have to manually update for Daylight Savings twice per year, and I have to think there's a more natural, elegant way to do this than the hackish "offset" I calculated. Has anyone come across a nicer way to do this, that takes into account DST?

Comment: write 2 scripts one for each. then switch case them based on time of year.

Comment: +1 for the question. Your code looks way overly complex for this, but I'm still interested to see what others come up with as a solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is few bugs in your code and I do not have to read it too carefully to say that. Never use arithmetic like that when  working with time. There is way too many wierd things like leap seconds that will break your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) class for this:

```
$hottimes = array (
    array(
        'start'=> new DateTime('Sun 11:00:00 America/Chicago'),
        'stop'=> new DateTime('Sun 12:00:00 America/Chicago')
    ),
    array(
        'start'=> new DateTime('Sun 18:00:00 America/Chicago'),
        'stop'=> new DateTime('Sun 19:00:00 America/Chicago')
    ),
    array(
        'start'=> new DateTime('Tue 19:00:00 America/Chicago'),
        'stop'=> new DateTime('Tue 20:00:00 America/Chicago')
    ),
    array(
        'start'=> new DateTime('Wed 06:00:00 America/Chicago'),
        'stop'=> new DateTime('Wed 07:00:00 America/Chicago')
    ),
    array(
        'start'=> new DateTime('Wed 11:00:00 America/Chicago'),
        'stop'=> new DateTime('Wed 12:00:00 America/Chicago')
    )
);

$now = new DateTime();

foreach($hottimes as $hotime) {
    if($now >= $hotime['start'] && $now < $hotime['stop']) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You should not use UNIX timestamps for such things. Using DateTime is the preferred way for that. Also read the comment of Sven. (thanks)

Comment: That's what timezones are for. They define the local time offset during the year, especially with regards to daylight saving time. Because of that it is important to choose the right timezone identifier, otherwise the clock will change at the wrong moment. Do not try to do the same thing with unix timestamps.

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl and @Sven! A much more beautiful solution. :-)

Comment: Hopefully you now 'save' daylight time ;)  Note that the DateTime object supports comparison using the `< > <= >=` operators. I've not explicitly mentioned this in the answer but I'm using them.